# Java JButton Only Doing some calls on double-click

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, double-click

So I have a massive project due soon, and for whatever reason my JButton's in my grid will call my incMoves() method which updates the private state of the move counter, but on the other hand, will not update the grid as it should be until i click the same button again.
The incMoves() method is called both times, so my move counter is completely out of whack.

Here is the code for my button:

class genWindow:
http://pastebin.com/SJ4wzYX0

class Jam: http://pastebin.com/87nqPBYP

Here is my test file: (txt)

```
6 5
4
0 3 2 3
3 1 3 3
3 0 5 0
2 0 2 1
```

Let me know if more information is needed.

Other than debugging the program with breakpoints within the ActionListener inner class to check whether it was actually making it in to the actionPerformed method, I don't know what else to attempt to fix it. I'm reasonably new to swing, and am rather confused by this, considering no errors or noticeable changes happen, besides the colors not switching.

The car buttons should be shifting depending on the large if statements in the actionPerformed method, and then updating grid with the addGrid function. The move counter is incremented, although the buttons don't actually shift unless clicked again.

Comment: Can you post a more complete and compilable code to show us the problem? Take a look at http://sscce.org/

Comment: "Let me know if more information is needed." Indeed it is. What have you tried to fix this problem? Please recall that StackOverflow is not a debugging service.

Comment: Drogba, I have thrown in the test file, and required classes to have a fully compilable program.

Comment: There are a lot of `return` statements in side you're `actionPerformed` method that may be preventing the UI from been updated..

Comment: You're rebuilding your UI and each click? This is not only inefficient, but it can cause all ends of problems...

Comment: I can not even begin to explain how much you just saved me. I had given up on the question because nobody had responded in upwards of 40 minutes, and your last post was the exact answer to the problem, and I had completely overlooked it. Sorry for the late response, I was busy freaking out trying to fix it and hand it in in time. It works perfectly so thank you!

Comment: And yea, I have no clue how to make it efficient. haha our professor said basically "Hey theres a java thing called swing and it makes GUI's.. now make something like UnBlock Me and have a solver function that can solve it for you as well." so I had no clue what I was doing.